# How to make orientDB avoid null

Tags: orientdb

When I execute code below,

```
select expand(distinct(@rid)) from (
  select from V
  where @rid = 'number not exist'
)
```

it returns

```
OCommandExecutionException:
     expression item '@rid' cannot be resolved because current record is NULL
```

This inside select is just for test and it returns no record.

I want `null` to be returned if select returns no record
and `expand(distinct(@rid))` if select returns some `@rid`.

The environment is OrientDB 2.1.5 and it occurs both in console and studio.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version are you using?
Are you trying this query in studio or console?

Comment: OrientDB 2.1.5 and both in console and studio.

I think it is because I tried to expand something null, I just want to know is there any good method such as using if() to avoid expanding null.

Answer (score 1):

Your query works correctly in version 2.1.7:

```
OrientDB console v.2.1.7-SNAPSHOT (build 4) www.orientdb.com
...
orientdb> connect ...

orientdb {db=demo}> select expand(distinct(@rid)) from (select from V where @rid = 'number not exist')

0 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.076 sec(s).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple javascript function as the following

```
var g=orient.getGraph();
var b=g.command("sql","select from V where @rid = #12:0");
if(b.length>0){
    var c=g.command("sql","select expand(distinct(@rid)) from ( select from V where @rid = #12:0)");
    return c;
}
else
  return null;
```

and call it from console or studio

```
select expand(result) from (select yourFunction() as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
SELECT expand(ifnull(@rid, 'null')) 
FROM V WHERE @rid = 'number not exist'
```

It will expand the record if exists, otherwise return empty.