# How to skip null records in Orientdb while using group by clause

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

When I execute following query:

```
SELECT count(*) as count, $new_source as name 
from news 
LET $new_source = if(eval("source.indexof('Other') === 0"), "Other", source)
where country_id = "111111"
group by $new_source
```

it throws an error saying:

> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException:
>   expression item 'source' cannot be resolved because current record is
>   NULL

It works well if there is at least one record for given country_id in the "news" class, but if there is no record for given country_id then it is throwing this error.

As I am using generic query for all news records irrespective of country_id, I want empty record set should be return if no record is there for specific country.

I have also tried with using orientdb's ifnull function to skip null values, something like this:

```
SELECT count(*) as count, $new_source as name from news LET $new_source = ifnull(source, 0, if(eval("source.indexof('Other') === 0"), "Other", source)) where country_id = "111111" group by $new_source
```

but it is not working, and throwing the same error.

I am using OrientDb 2.1.8. I don't want to use javascript function and call it from console (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992181/how-to-make-orientdb-avoid-null))

Is there any way, I can skip null values while using if with group by?

Comment: Hi, what type the property 'source' is? String, Integer or other?

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi it's of type String.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, I can't reproduce your issue, could you add the screenshot of what your class contains, please? Or a DB test if it's not a problem :)

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi, Hi, here'e the things you have asked for:


Query result for "Select from news" : https://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/34821041909318dd7fc23de1e4b65540.png


Query result for "SELECT count(*) as count, $new_source as name from news LET $new_source = if(eval("source.indexof('Other') === 0"), "Other", source) where country_id = "1110" group by $new_source":

https://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/e842d70e18d9f1252f9587ceed3754e7.png


Actual schema:
https://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/a9f327ada1a880ee2d94354045316153.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to modify your query and maybe I found a solution:

```
select count(*) as count,name
from (
  select if(eval("source.indexof('Other') === 0"), "Other", source) as name 
  from news where country_id = "111111")  
group by name
```

I have no errors and correctly no results.

[image]

```
select count(*) as count,name
from (
  select if(eval("source.indexof('Other') === 0"), "Other", source) as name 
  from news where country_id = "1110")  
group by name
```

Here correctly I have results

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

remove your index and re-creates another index of type full-text with engine Lucene.

[image]

Querying you get this result:

[image]